# Add GoDaddy Website to RDS Security Group

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website hosted on GoDaddy. I'm trying to create a PHP form that will add inputted data to a MySQL RDS database. The form is working beautifully if I allow connections from **any** IP in my RDS security settings. However, as soon as I restrict incoming connections to my site's actual IP address, the connection fails: `Connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dakotasverses.czonzcxespne.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)`

Per my cPanel dashboard, my GoDaddy website's IP address is 107.xxx.xx.xxx. So my security group's inbound connection rule is set to allow All traffic from 107.xxx.xx.xxx/32. But again, this doesn't seem to be working.

Note: The reason I'm not sharing PHP form code is that the form itself is working properly, as evidenced by the successful test when using open IP permissions.

Comment: Be careful with this. I'm not sure GoDaddy is obligated to keep your server's IP consistent and they may move your site to another instance for load balancing reasons.

Comment: This form is just for my own personal use. So if it breaks, I could easily make the necessary correction without users being affected.

Comment: You shouldn't be restricting data entry based on an IP address. Instead you should look into things like SQLi prevention and the principle of least privilege to ensure integrity of your data.

Comment: @ObsidianAge That's not relevant here. This is about using a remote database with a hosted PHP application and providing limited white-list access to that application.

Comment: You should add your own IP to the security group to see if that's being applied correctly in order to see if you're even applying it properly.

Comment: @tadman Done. I'm currently working with my data via an ODBC connection, and I have an associated rule that allows this connection when made from my personal IP address. No problems there.

Comment: Next step is to check if that GoDaddy connection is coming from the IP you think it is because it might be coming from one or more servers depending on their internal shared hosting architecture. Quick way to check is to load [http://api.ipify.org](http://api.ipify.org).

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to check on that. But for some reason, my RDS error log is empty even though I've enabled error logging. Is there another way to check which IP is being used?

Comment: godaddy is a crap host, as your using RDS, when not host on ec2

Comment: Migrating my entire site seems like a complicated solution.

Comment: moved hosts of my personal sites a few times over the last decade, its really quite easy, moved work sites and servers as well, not much harder. Short term pain for ling term gain :-)